# My program creates a file named date.in but it is not inserting all the numbers

Tags: c

> Write a C  program that reads from the keyboard a natural number n
>   with up to 9 digits and creates the text file data.out containing the
>   number n and all its non-zero prefixes, in a single line, separated by
>   a space, in order decreasing in value. Example: for n = 10305 the data
>   file.out will contain the numbers: 10305 1030 103 10 1.

This is what I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{    
 int n; 
 FILE *fisier;
 fisier=fopen("date.in","w");
 printf("n= \n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 fprintf(fisier,"%d",n);

 while(n!=0)    
 {
    fisier=fopen("date.in","r");
     n=n/10;
     fprintf(fisier,"%d",n);    
 }

 fclose(fisier);
}
```

Comment: For one thing, get rid of the `fopen` call inside the `while` loop - the file is already open.

Comment: Why do you open `fisier` inside your loop? Open it once in write mode (`"w"`), then `fprint` to it, then close it.

Comment: Also `fopen` may fail. You need to check if `fopen` returns `NULL` and display an error message and abort if so.

Comment: ... and repléace `"%d"`with `"%d "`, otherwise you might be surprised by the content of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1. Function calls may return error. You need to check that every time.

   `fisier=fopen("date.in","w");`

   This should have been followed by an error check. To understand more on what it return, first thing you should do is read the man page for that function. See [man page for fopen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). If there is an error in opening the file, it will return NULL and errno is set to a value which indicates what error occurred.

   ```
   if (NULL == fisier)
   {
       // Error handling code
       ;
   }
   ```
2. Your next requirement is separating the numbers by a space. There isn't one. The following should do it.

   ```
   fprintf(fisier, "%d ", n);
   ```
3. The next major problem is opening the file in a loop. Its like you are trying to open a door which is already open.

   ```
   fisier=fopen("date.in","r");

   if(NULL == fisier)
   {
       // Error handling code
       ;
   }

   while(n!=0)    
   {
       n=n/10;
       fprintf(fisier,"%d",n);    
   }

   fclose(fisier);
   ```
4. A minor issue that you aren't checking is the number is not having more than 9 digits.

   ```
   if(n > 999999999)
   ```

   is apt after you get a number. If you want to deal with negative numbers as well, you can modify this condition the way you want.

In a nutshell, at least to start with, the program should be something similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Need a buffer to read the file into it. 64 isn't a magic number. 
// To print a 9 digit number followed by a white space and then a 8 digit number.. 
// and so on, you need little less than 64 bytes. 
// I prefer keeping the memory aligned to multiples of 8.

char buffer[64];

int main(void)
{
    size_t readBytes = 0;
    int n = 0;

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Open the file
    FILE *pFile = fopen("date.in", "w+");
    if(NULL == pFile)
    {
        // Prefer perror() instead of printf() for priting errors
        perror("\nError: ");
        return 0;
    }

    while(n != 0)
    {
        // Append to the file
        fprintf(pFile, "%d ", n);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    // Done, close the file
    fclose(pFile);

    printf("\nPrinting the file: ");

    // Open the file
    pFile = fopen("date.in", "r");
    if(NULL == pFile)
    {
        // Prefer perror() instead of printf() for priting errors
        perror("\nError: ");
        return 0;
    }

    // Read the file
    while((readBytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, pFile)) > 0)
    {
        // Preferably better way to print the contents of the file on stdout!
        fwrite(buffer, 1, readBytes, stdout);
    }

    printf("\nExiting..\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Remember: The person reading your code may not be aware of all the requirements, so comments are necessary. Secondly, I understand english to a decent level but I don't know what 'fisier' means. Its recommended to name variables in such a way that its easy to understand the purpose of the variable. For example, `pFile` is a pointer to a file. `p` in the variable immediately gives an idea that its a pointer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To draw a conclusion from all the comments:

`fopen` returns a file handle when successfull and `NULL` otherwise. Opening a file twice might result in an error (it does on my machine), such that `fisier` is set to `NULL` inside the loop. Obvioulsy `fprintf` to `NULL` wont do anything.

- You only need to call `fopen` once, so remove it from the loop. After that it will work as intended.
- It's alwas good to check if the `fopen` succeeded or not:

  ```
  FILE *fisier;
  fisier=fopen("date.in","w");

  if(!fisier) { /* handle error */ }
  ```
- You print no spaces between the numbers. Maybe that's intended, but maybe

  ```
  fprintf(fisier,"%d ",n);
  ```

  would be better.